# Html in a DOMElement with ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, xpath

I'm using Zend Framework with Zend_Dom_Query to get a page and find in paragraphs.

Here my source code :

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($newsData);

$content = '';
$results = $dom->query('p');
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $content .= $result->nodeValue;
}
```

With that, if the paragraph contains others html elements, they're deleted.
For example, if the code is : `<p><a href="#">My link</a></p>`, the nodeValue (or textContent) is `My link` and not `<a href="#">My Link</a>`.

How can I keep the html in the content of a DOMElement ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    function getInnerHTML($Node)
    {

        $Document = new DOMDocument();
        $Document->appendChild($Document->importNode($Node,true));
        return $Document->saveHTML();
    }

    function domAction ()
    {
        $this->_helper->ViewRenderer->setNoRender ();
        $newsData = '<body><p><a href="#">My link</a></p></body>';
        $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($newsData);

        $content = '';
        $results = $dom->query('p/*');
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $content .= $this->getInnerHtml ($result);
        }

        echo htmlentities ($content);
    }
}
```